# How to draw a marker that covers other markers?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, scatter-plot

I draw a scatter plot using Plotly:

```
go.Scatter(x=df["x"], y=df["y"], mode='markers')
```

[image: Present]

I want to add a red circle that covers drawn markers like below:

[image: What I want]

How can I add the red circle?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [Shapes section](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/) on Plotly tutorials. It has an example that accomplishes what you just asked.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

# Generate data
x0 = np.random.normal(2, 0.45, 300)
y0 = np.random.normal(2, 0.45, 300)

# Create figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add scatter traces
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x0, y=y0, mode="markers"))

# Add shapes
fig.add_shape(type="circle",
    xref="x", yref="y",
    x0=min(x0), y0=min(y0),
    x1=max(x0), y1=max(y0),
    opacity=0.2,
    fillcolor="red",
    line_color="red",
)

# Hide legend
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)

fig.show()
```